Colored boxes with arrows spiralling inwards and outwards
Here is some tikz code that makes a nice loop with text.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
% Useful packages
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{syscol}{rgb}{0, 0.51, 0.153}
\definecolor{modelcol}{HTML}{339999}
\definecolor{methodcol}{HTML}{3399CC}
\definecolor{implementationcol}{HTML}{99CCCC}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}


\begin{document}



\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\newcommand{\arcarrow}[8]% inner radius, middle radius, outer radius, start angle, end angle, tip protusion angle, options, text
{   \pgfmathsetmacro{\rin}{#1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rmid}{#2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\rout}{#3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\astart}{#4}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\aend}{#5}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\atip}{#6}
    \fill[#7] (\astart:\rin) arc (\astart:\aend:\rin) -- (\aend+\atip:\rmid) -- (\aend:\rout) arc (\aend:\astart:\rout) -- (\astart+\atip:\rmid) -- cycle;
    \path[decoration={text along path, text={#8}, text align={align=center}, raise=-0.5ex},decorate] (\astart+\atip:\rmid) arc (\astart+\atip:\aend+\atip:\rmid);
}




\begin{tikzpicture}

  \tikzset
  {
    myCircle/.style=
    {
      red,
      path fading=fade out,
    }
  }
  \fill[myCircle, purple] (-2,-1) circle (3);
  \fill[myCircle, purple] (1,-1) circle (2);
  \fill[myCircle, purple] (3.1,-1.7) circle (2);
   % \fill[even odd rule,red!30] circle (3.8) circle (3.2);
   % \foreach \x in {0,60,...,300} 
   % {   \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{\x+20}{\x+70}{5}{red,draw=red!50!black,very thick}{text \x}
    {   \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{60-2}{0+0+5}{-5}{modelcol,draw=black!20!black,thin,font=\bf}{Implementation}
    }
    {   \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{60+60-2}{60+2}{-5}{methodcol,draw=black!50!black,thin}{Method}
    }
    {   \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{120+60-5}{120+2}{-5}{implementationcol,draw=black!50!black,thin}{Model}
    }
    {   \arcarrow{3}{3.5}{4}{180+5}{300+60-5}{-5}{syscol,draw=black!50!black,thin}{System of Interest                  Experiment} 
   }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


How do I change it so that the arrows spiral inwards with many repetitions? Here is what I could achieve with GPT. It seems there are many good ideas, but it does not run.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{syscol}{rgb}{0, 0.51, 0.153}
\definecolor{modelcol}{HTML}{339999}
\definecolor{methodcol}{HTML}{3399CC}
\definecolor{implementationcol}{HTML}{99CCCC}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\spiralarrow}[7]% inner radius, radius increment per degree, start angle, end angle, tip protrusion angle, options, text
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rin}{#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\dr}{#2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\astart}{#3}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\aend}{#4}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\atip}{#5}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\delta}{0.5} % Width of the arrow
  \def\spiralpathinner{
    plot[domain=\astart:\aend,samples=200,variable=\t]
      ({ (\rin + (\t - \astart)*\dr ) * cos(\t d) }, { (\rin + (\t - \astart)*\dr ) * sin(\t d) })
  }
  \def\spiralpathouter{
    plot[domain=\aend:\astart,samples=200,variable=\t]
      ({ (\rin + (\t - \astart)*\dr + \delta ) * cos(\t d) }, { (\rin + (\t - \astart)*\dr + \delta ) * sin(\t d) })
  }
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\rtip}{\rin + (\aend - \astart + \atip)*\dr + \delta/2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtip}{\rtip * cos((\aend + \atip)d)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ytip}{\rtip * sin((\aend + \atip)d)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xstart}{\rtip * cos((\astart + \atip)d)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ystart}{\rtip * sin((\astart + \atip)d)}
  \fill[#6]
    \spiralpathinner
    --
    (\xtip,\ytip)
    --
    \spiralpathouter
    --
    (\xstart,\ystart)
    -- cycle;
  % Add text along the spiral
  \path[decoration={text along path, text={#7}, text align={center}, raise=-0.5ex}, decorate]
    plot[domain=\astart:\aend,samples=200,variable=\t]
      ({ (\rin + (\t - \astart)*\dr + \delta/2 ) * cos(\t d) }, { (\rin + (\t - \astart)*\dr + \delta/2 ) * sin(\t d) });
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Parameters for the spiral
  \def\rin{1} % Initial radius
  \def\dr{0.05} % Radius increment per degree

  % First arrow
  \spiralarrow{\rin}{\dr}{0}{270}{10}{implementationcol}{Implementation}
  % Second arrow
  \spiralarrow{\rin}{\dr}{270}{540}{10}{methodcol}{Method}
  % Third arrow
  \spiralarrow{\rin}{\dr}{540}{810}{10}{modelcol}{Model}
  % Fourth arrow
  \spiralarrow{\rin}{\dr}{810}{1080}{10}{syscol}{System of Interest}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


The answer below uses the wheelchart package, which I wrote.
The text is given to the key arc data. The direction is determined by the key arc data dir and the position by the key arc data pos. The shape is determined by the key plot. The arrow is obtained with the key slices arrow.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\definecolor{syscol}{rgb}{0, 0.51, 0.153}
\definecolor{modelcol}{HTML}{339999}
\definecolor{methodcol}{HTML}{3399CC}
\definecolor{implementationcol}{HTML}{99CCCC}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  arc data=\WCvarB,
  arc data dir={\WCmidangle<180?-1:1},
  arc data pos=0.5,
  data=,
  domain=0:900,
  gap polar=3,
  plot={{#1}:{(((#1)*pi/180+15)^2-1)/300+(#2)-0.25}},
  radius={0}{0.5},
  samples=100,
  slices arrow={-1}{0},
  slices style={\WCvarA,draw=black},
  value=sqrt(3+\WCcount*pi*(pi+6)/7)-sqrt(3+(\WCcount-1)*pi*(pi+6)/7)
]{%
  modelcol/Model,
  methodcol/Method,
  implementationcol/Implementation,
  syscol/System of Interest%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


